# null check in UDF in Conceptual model?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4

I have added a UDF in the conceptual data model under the `<DefiningExpression>` tag.
Is it possible to add a null check or a replace in the `<DefiningExpression>` tag.

```
<Function Name="FullName" ReturnType="String">
    <Parameter Name="c" Type="IsolateDataModel.User_UserInformation" />
        <DefiningExpression>
            <!--c.Prefix + " " + c.FirstName + " " + 
            c.LastName + " " + c.PostFix-->
            ISNULL(c.FirstName,"")
      </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
```

I get the values when the values are not null however some columns like the prefix and postfix are `nullable` and do have `NULL` values. How to do a check on this inside this or anywhere else? I think the null values are causing an exception and hence I get the entire expression as empty.Instead, I want to just replace them with "" if null.

Answer (score 0):

The `<DefiningExpression>` element [must contain Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489503.aspx). Entity SQL does not have an `ISNULL` function, so you'll have to use the more clumsy [CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399229):

```
CASE WHEN c.FirstName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE c.FirstName END
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I opted for another way of doing the same. I just added an extension method for the entity object in question and I suppose it does the same in the background. Also, I get to write a normal C# function with full LINQ features.